# Opt-In status of a particular number in gupshup api

Tags: gupshup

I am integrating WhatsApp thru gupshup Platform. Need to know how to check opt-In status of a particular number in gupshup api. I gives me the list of all users. After sending the opt-in link to another user I need to check the opt-in status of that user only

Answer (score 0):

Go to your WhatsApp Dashboard, you will see "View Opt-In" WhatsApp Dashboard-Send Message:
[image: WhatsApp Dashboard-Send Message]

You will see list of all Opt-in users
[image: List of User Opt-In]